# Visual Studio 2019 - ASAN reported issues at app startup (QT)

Tags: visual-studio, qt, address-sanitizer

I have a simple windows QT app. At startup I receive the following if I compile with ASAN support:

```
AddressSanitizer: attempting free on address which was not malloc()-ed
Address 0x012e4b915160 is a wild pointer
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: bad-free
```

This is a simple program, sow in other places that there are some issues with ASAN support (see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/crash-with-asan-and-setmaxstdio/1439907) wonder if there is a workaround for making a useable setup running ASAN on my QT app.

Comment: (sorry I didn't do a good search when initially asked my question, but now according to recommendations on Meta, this question should be a duplicate of my, since my has an answer)